# Nested conditionals and temporary loop variable with Thymeleaf

Tags: jsp, jstl, thymeleaf

I am moving the view-layer of a project from jsp to Thymeleaf and I struggle with this loop.

To create valid html output, I need to nest some `<c:if>`-tags which make the html look invalid at source level.

Additionally I make use of a variable `lastStorey` which tracks the instance of the previous iteration.

How could I re-recreate the same logic with Thymeleaf's `th:if` conditions?

Here is the code I am talking about:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="structure">
            <c:set var="lastStorey" value="" />
            <c:forEach items="${storeys}" var="c" varStatus="status">
                <c:if test="${lastStorey != c[0]}">
                    <c:if test="${not status.first}">
                        <span style="clear: left;"></span>
                        </div>
                    </c:if>
                    <div class="storey">
                </c:if>
                <a href="#"><button><i class="fa fa-music"></i></button></a>
                <c:set var="lastStorey" value="${c[0]}" />
                <c:if test="${status.last}"><span style="clear:left;"></span></c:if>
            </c:forEach>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

The complexity from the code example comes from the need to act on a change of property in the `${storeys}` list. It holds room objects with a `storey`-property.

I have now changed the code in a way that `${storeys}` is a map, which per entry has a list of rooms.

So I can simply interate the map, and nested inside, iterate the rooms.

This has led to a considerable simplification of the html code.

Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Before you migrate to Thymeleaf, just think about that JSP template. Look at the amount of logic inside of it. Is it good to have that logic in the untestable place? I don't think so.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct?  It looks like you close a `div` tag within the `c:if` block and you close a `c:if` within another `div`.